# NSMutableArray not accessible throughout my class?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, nsmutablearray

I'm really frustrated after spending like three hours googling around to solve this problem!! It's probably an easy solution to it aswell.

I'm creating a really simple TableView app for the iPhone. It's supposed to fetch an XML-document and parse it (already fixed) and then put the data into objects called HPobject!
One HPobject represents one day of data from the XML-file. Anyhow!

**Then I want the object to be stored in a NSMutableArray** so I can grab it later when I'm creating the table rows. But I can't access it! My NSMutableArray is ALWAYS null! No matter what I do!

Here's my code:

```
//THE .h FILE
#import "TBXML.h"
#import "HPobject.h"

@interface RootViewController : UITableViewController {
    NSMutableArray *listOfItems;
}

- (void)traverseElement:(TBXMLElement *)element;

//THE .m FILE
#import "RootViewController.h"
#import "HPobject.h"

@implementation RootViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{   
    NSMutableArray *listOfItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    TBXML * tbxml = [[TBXML tbxmlWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.hpprov.se/istasts.php?q=xxxxxxx"]] retain];

    if (tbxml.rootXMLElement)
        [self traverseElement:tbxml.rootXMLElement]; //Works fine!

    [tbxml release];
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (void) traverseElement:(TBXMLElement *)element {    
    do {
//Lots of parsing code which all works fine and gets me the variables up next!

            HPobject *currentObject = [[HPobject alloc] init];
            currentObject.antalRegistrerade = numRegistrerade;
            currentObject.inkomstBrutto = numBrutto;
            currentObject.inkomstNetto = numNetto;

            [listOfItems addObject:currentObject];

            NSLog(@"Array: %@", listOfItems); //RETURNS null!
            NSLog(@"Reg: %@, Net: %@, Brutt: %@", currentObject.antalRegistrerade, currentObject.inkomstNetto, currentObject.inkomstBrutto); //Returns the correct values!

            NSLog(@"%d stycken!", listOfItems.count); //Returns 0!! :(
            [currentObject release];

    } while ((element = element->nextSibling));  
}
```

Comment: Why does is return NULL?!?? :( And why is the count 0??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are defining listOfItems locally in viewDidLoad and then you try to access that in another method.

Make sure you are using an instance variable defined in your interface definition (header).

replace this line in viewDidLoad:

```
NSMutableArray *listOfItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

with

```
listOfItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! And... how do I do that? I know I should read a book on Objective-C and its fantastic implementation, and I will, but for now I need a quick answer!
Thank you!

Comment: Even better would be to use a (synthesized) getter/setter: `self.listOfItems = [NSMutableArray array];`

Comment: See my solution - simply remove "NSMutableArray *" from viewDidLoad.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose that listOfItems is an ivar. So to fix your problem change this:

```
NSMutableArray *listOfItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

to this

```
listOfItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

Comment: As a rule, you should use instance variables starting with an underscore character. That makes it much more obvious that you are assigning to an instance variable.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the scope of your array. You have created that as a variable of another method. It will not visible in others. Make an instance var.